# drupal 7 page tpl theme

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i develop my web site using drupal 7 and there page "about_us" is different design structure than others pages and i need to create specific tpl file for just this page.. i found solution page--node--[nid].tpl.php  but this solution not professional ... how to avoid this way and create tpl file depends on node title ??

thanks..

Comment: plz i need to implement progress bar using drupal 7 ?
i search for this topic and not found any thing  if any body know what steps .. how increment the bar depending on function ??

i need make this topic helpful for another person need this problem solution.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are referring to here requires amending the preprocessing information to accomplish this.

I would suggest looking at http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions  as this seems to detail exactly how to do this.

hope this help.